# What does it mean "to have a crush on somebody"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've heard in many movies that one character says "I have a crush on him/her".

I'm not sure what it means. Somewhere, i read that it means that person A likes person B but A cannot tell B. Somewhere else, it was written that it means person A is with someone he/she shouldn't be. ( Like an older person ). One of my friends told me that it means that person A doesn't love person B but somehow A likes B. I'm confused about what it means.

My questions are :

> 1. What does it exactly mean "to have a crush on somebody"?
> 2. Is it a bad thing? Should someone be ashamed because he/she has a crush on somebody?
> 3. Is it a rude thing to say?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?  "crush" as a noun should have a definition related to romance.

Comment: @JohnFeltz i know its related ... i want the exact meaning sir :)

Comment: @Arman: The dictionary shows the exact meaning. I think you're looking for the _nuances_, which the dictionary doesn't always provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To have a crush (on someone)" is a light-hearted and slightly juvenile way to express a strong affection for someone.  It is *mostly* used to talk about young people's feelings, and does not normally describe adult emotions.

If applied to adults it *can* be an insult to imply the person is or acts immature.  This depends greatly on context, however, as it can also be used as a compliment to imply someone is acting or looking youthful.

A "crush" doesn't have to be on a peer or someone of similar age.  A young person can have a crush on an older (even a much older) celebrity or any other person.  Also, a crush can often be one-sided, implying that the affection isn't returned by the other person (referred to as "*unrequited* love").

By using "crush" instead of some similar term, it implies that the feeling isn't *serious* and is likely to be *temporary*.  Of course many young people will disagree with this, but that's the nature of youthful crushes.  No one should be ashamed of a crush, but they might be deeply embarrassed if talked about in front of them.

How young is "young" can vary widely by who is talking.  At my age, I might use "crush" for anyone under 30, but I'm a grumpy old curmudgeon.

Answer (score 4):

It is neither rude nor bad to have a

> crush

on *someone*, it simply means one has an "attraction and (possibly) affection" for *someone*.
It is usually used to describe this attraction in a playful way

> He has a **crush** on his third grade teacher.
>   She has a **crush** on her personal trainer.
>   The groupies have a **crush** on the lead singer.

Terms which may be used as a synonyms are "infatuation" or  "[puppy love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zI2hgm65WhE&t=0m15s)".

On the scale of attraction

> obsession *(most intense)*
>   undying love
>   smitten
>   infatuation
>   **crush**
>   like *(least intense)*